# Not able to import pod framework in my test app

Tags: ios, git, frameworks, cocoapods, xcode8

I have a dynamic framework from a 3rd party customer.I don't have the source code for that framework.I am planning to include this 3rd party framework inside my dynamic framework.
I researched and found out that umbrella frameworks is discouraged by Apple and is not the best approach to do this.So i decided to create a Pod for the 3rd part framework which I would include in my dynamic framework.

I created the Pod with 3rd Party framework.It passed all the validations and I pushed that successfully to repo as well.

I have edited and included my framework 'TestNewSample' in podfile like this:-

source 'https://github.com/xxxx/yyyyy.git'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'NewTest' do
    pod 'TestNewSample'
end

Now in my dynamic framework when i perform pod install,it installs all the contents of 'TestNewSample' in my repo under Pods folder.
But when i try to import the 'TestNewSample',it says "Module not found".

I am able to access other public pods.The issue is with only my pods. 
I have tried to use it in a single view application project.But there also no help.

Can anyone please help and let me know what I missing out here?

Comment: After `pod install` command, did you build it? As I know, dynamic frameworks has to be built before using.

Comment: Yes I clean,built it.Do you think my approach is correct?I mean can we use a dynamic framework inside a Pod for which we dont have source files(.m)?